# API difference between onedrive and office365

Tags: office365

I am a developer that design some features to connected to personal onedrive cloud storage to manage my data.

But now I'm confused about onedrive for business and pure onedrive.

I read some articles that discussed about the difference between onedrive and onedrive business.

But I'm still confused about the "API reuse" for developers.

It seems like onedrive live sdk is only for personal version, office365 api for onedrive for business.

So that's the problem:
1) could I use onedrive API to access data from the account of onedrive for business?
2) could I use onedrive for business API to access data from the account of onedrive personal version?
3) office365 API (for personal/business) are the same as API for onedrive fro business?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike,

First and foremost, I'm no Microsoft employee or MVP, but I have had to deal with exactly this issue so let me try to shed some light on this based on my experiences.

To be blunt, the only similarity between OneDrive for Business and OneDrive (formerly Skydrive) is the name.

OneDrive for consumers (Skydrive) uses the LiveAPI and is nothing remotely like OneDrive from Business from Office365. In fact, if you dig into it deeper you'll see OneDrive for Business is really much more closely related to SharePoint than Skydrive.

In fact, up until last year there was no API for OneDrive for Business, only recently (in the last 12 months) did Microsoft setup Office365 APIs for OneDrive for Business and SharePoint/Exchange, etc.

So, for all the questions you asked, No, Nope, No sir.

:)

Sorry.

Update (2017):
There is now a "OneDrive API" that works for OneDrive for Consumers, OneDrive Office365, AND SharePoint Office365. Yes, Virginia, there is a Santa Claus! https://dev.onedrive.com/